How to update custom tag Key in GCP compute engine
I have created a cutom tag key and associated value for a particular instance in GCP compute engine. How i can update/delete the tag key by programatically by using google compute engine sdk in java?
Can someone guide me how i can do this? Please provide sample code if possible.

Please edit your question. There are two types of actions: set instance labels and set instance tags. They perform different functions. Please read the links to understand more. What are labels. What are tags.

The Java SDK documentation is here. Look for the SetLabels and SetTags methods. Then write code to learn how to use those interfaces.
